# WSL: visudo -c complains "parse error"

Tags: sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visudo

I'm having a problem trying to set a sudoer file in WSL.

So, I created a file `/etc/sudoers.d/wheel` containing the following one line:

```
%wheel  ALL = NOPASSWD: (ALL:ALL) ALL
```

But whenever I run `visudo -c`, it *always* complained, with some random characters. Here are three runs, one after another:

```
root@pepoluan-Asus:/etc/sudoers.d# visudo -c
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel: syntax error near line 1 <<<
parse error in K�� near line 1
root@pepoluan-Asus:/etc/sudoers.d# visudo -c
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel: syntax error near line 1 <<<
parse error in K��� near line 1
root@pepoluan-Asus:/etc/sudoers.d# visudo -c
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel: syntax error near line 1 <<<
parse error in K}8� near line 1
```

(Please note that the `�` sign represents an unknown unicode character, shown onscreen as a box with 4 hex digits within, but those characters refuse to appear here in AU.com)

What's going on here?

---

***EDIT:***

```
pepoluan@pepoluan-Asus:/mnt/c/Users/pepoluan$ file /etc/sudoers.d/wheel.disabled
/etc/sudoers.d/wheel.disabled: ASCII text
```

(I have temporarily renamed the file to `wheel.disabled` so it won't mess up with the `sudo` command.)

Comment: What does `file /etc/sudoers.d/wheel` say?

Comment: @steeldriver exactly what I have written there in the question.

Comment: @steeldriver oops, sorry, misunderstood your question. I did that, actually, and it said "ASCII text file"

Comment: Actually I think the non-printing characters are a separate issue (possibly to do with terminal encoding) - the error message is simply that you have the `NOPASSWD` in the wrong place, it needs to be `%wheel ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` (although personally I **dion't** recommend giving wide open admin access this way)